# Forest trust: SPN mismatch for non-fully-qualified name

Tags: kerberos, cifs, trust-relationship, spn

### Setup

All computers running Windows Server 2019.

#### Domain A

| Item | Value | Fully Qualified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Domain Name | `DomainA` | `DomainA.local` |
| User | `UserA` | `UserA@DomainA.local` |
| Server | `FileServer` | `FileServer.DomainA.local` |

#### Domain B

| Item | Value | Fully Qualified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Domain Name | `DomainB` | `DomainB.local` |
| User | `UserB` | `UserB@DomainB.local` |
| Server | `FileServer` | `FileServer.DomainB.local` |
| Worksation | `WorkStation` | `WorkStation.DomainB.local` |

#### Forest Trusts

- `DomainA.local` trusts `DomainB.local`
- `DomainB.local` trusts `DomainA.local`

### Scenarios

I present two scenarios below.  Scenario A works as expected.  I have a question about Scenario B.

#### Scenario A

`UserB@DomainB.local` logs into `WorkStation.DomainB.local` and then from the Run prompt tries to open `\\FileServer`.

Q: Which `FileServer` will appear?

- a) `FileServer.DomainA.local`
- b) `FileServer.DomainB.local`

A: (b) [obviously -- we are using a `DomainB` user on a `DomainB` workstation]

#### Scenario B

`UserA@DomainA.local` logs into `WorkStation.DomainB.local` and then from the Run command prompt tries to open `\\FileServer`.

Q: Which FileServer's shares will appear?

- a) `FileServer.DomainA.local` (because we are logged in with a `DomainA` username)
- b) `FileServer.DomainB.local` (because we are logged in to a `DomainB` computer)

A: None of the above.  Instead an error message will appear:

```
\\FileServer is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this nework resource.  Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

The target account name is incorrect
```

### Question

Can someone explain technically why Scenario B fails?  Specifically:

1. How does the string "`\\FileServer`" translate to a particular computer?

   - Is DNS used?  If not, what is used?
   - Does it resolve to `FileServer.DomainA.local` or `FileServer.DomainB.local`?
2. How SPN is related, specifically the fact that `setspn -L FileServer` shows non-fully-qualified names such as `HOST/FileServer` as well as fully-qualified entries such as `HOST/FileServer.DomainB.local`

#### My Guess

1. DNS (and arguably common sense) resolves `FileServer` to `FileServer.DomainB.local`
2. However, `\\FileServer` (CIFS/double-back-slash) resolves to `FileServer.DomainA.local`.
3. SPN (whatever that is) is "resolving" to `FileServer.DomainB.local`
4. The DomainA/DomainB mismatch in (2) and (3) is the source of `The target account name is incorrect`